# Is there a DSL/gem for executing external commands in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Ok, there's a lot of ways one can execute external commands in Ruby: http://tech.natemurray.com/2007/03/ruby-shell-commands.html. I'm looking for library that can make it easier for me. I've found, so far:

- http://shell-executer.rubyforge.org
- http://gitorious.org/gnoxys/arh

Are there any more?

Answer (score 3):

Why on earth do you need a gem for that?  You can just run

```
`command`
```

and its done..  How could it possibly be made any easier?

Comment: I expressed myself in a clumsy way. What I want is something that can help me with error handling, read from stderr and other nice stuff. Kind of like highline helps me building command line interfaces or Sinatra let's me create a web app through a nice DSL. Do I make any sense?

Comment: ah ok.. yes, that kinda changes everything..